# Wordpress ACF fields how to get_option from custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type

I use ACF and have a page template called 'About' which my 'About Us' page uses. I also have a homepage template that uses fields from my 'homepage field group'. My 'About Us' page shows ACF fields from the 'About field group' **AS WELL AS** some fields from my 'Homepage field group'.

I get the fields from my homepage group by referencing the ACF fields with the following php code:

```
<?php $home = get_option('page_on_front'); ?>
<h3><?php the_field('featured_text' , $home); ?></h3>
<p><?php the_field('intro');?></p>
<h2><?php the_field('header', $home);?></h2>
```

The `H3` is from the homepage field group on the homepage and the paragraph is from my 'About Us' page intro field from the 'About field group'.

I want to do something similar but pull in fields from a custom post type (NOT the homepage).

My custom post type is called 'Common Modules' (slug = common_modules).

Is there a way to do this e.g:

```
<?php $custom_post_type = get_post_type('Common Modules'); ?>
<h3><?php the_field('featured_text' , $custom_post_type); ?></h3>
<p><?php the_field('intro');?></p>
<h2><?php the_field('header', $custom_post_type);?></h2>
```

**I have quite a few fields on my page that reference the homepage fields, so i need to be able to call $custom_post_type frequently throughout my page.**

I cant figure it out?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Does your ```cpt``` have a specific post with the ```featured_text``` field? If so, what's the id of that post? We could retrieve the value from its id.

Comment: Yes its one post with id 495.

Comment: Ok just updated my answer, see if that would work for you!

Comment: Perfect. Brilliant help. Thanks for your patience :-)

Comment: Not a problem! I'm glad that it was helpful! BTW, you could do the same thing for your "$home" value. You could use your page id instead of using ```get_option```.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a custom query using `WP_Query`:

```php
<?php
$custom_query = new WP_Query(array(
  "post_type" => "common_modules" // use the name of your cpt here. The name when you register it using "register_post_type"
));

while ($custom_query->have_posts()) {
  $custom_query->the_post();?>
<h3><?php the_field('featured_text'); // you don't need to pass the second argument. it defaults to the current post in the while loop?></h3>
<?php };
wp_reset_postdata();
?>

<p><?php the_field('intro');?></p>
```

Let me know if it works for you!

---

**UPDATE**

```php
<h3><?php the_field('featured_text', '495'); //You could use the id of that specific post to get the value of your acf field?></h3>

<p><?php the_field('intro');?></p>

<h2><?php the_field('header', '495');?></h2>
```

Comment: You write php in a different style to my template file. How do i write your code in my php format?

Comment: In your template file just include opening and closing php tags. I'll edit my answer and include those tags for you, so you could just "copy/past".

Comment: I just updated my answer, just "copy/past" it in your template file and it'll output your field value if it's not empty!

Comment: Thanks. It works but not properly because my template references fields from the homepage ACF fields and also ACF fields from another field group. So when i add your code, it gets the fields from my homepage group but no longer get the fields from my other group. Thats why i need to specify a $home so it knows to get fields specifically from the homepage field group. Is that possible?

Comment: Yes absolutely doable! So you've assigned these ```field groups``` to different custom post types? How many "custom post types" you have? what are they called? we could include those to our ```$custom_query``` as well.

Comment: Ive updated my question to fully explain my needs. Does it make sense? Your code works but when i  try and get <?php the_field('intro');?> from the About Page group it doesnt show. For now ive only one CPT but am likely to have more.

Comment: Thanks, but like i said, i frequently have to reference different homepage fields, so need a simplified code. See the edits in my question.